# How to rewrite /wp-admin/admin.php?page=something to /wp-admin/something using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to configure my .htaccess so that when someone navigates to the path `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=something`, the path `/wp-admin/something` is shown in the browser, and the content from `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=something` is served.

If I navigate to `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=something` the page is served correctly. However, `/wp-admin/something` doesn't serve the content, instead it shows the default 404 page I have in my site.

My .htaccess config:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?wp-admin/?$ /wp-admin/admin.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteBase /
ReWriteCond %{ENV:ENVIRONMENT} !^development$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>

RedirectMatch 301 ^/kundeoplysninger https://signup.kredslob.dk/kundeoplysninger
RedirectMatch 301 ^/mobilepay /

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: "Currently nothing happens when i navigate to **either of the endpoints**" - You need to resolve why `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=something` is not working as intended - that doesn't seem to be related to your `.htaccess` file. (?)

Comment: I have updated my original question. The `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=something` endpoint works correctly, it's the intended one that doesnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when someone navigates to the path `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=something`, the path `/wp-admin/something` is shown in the browser

This requires an external redirect. This is OK for users who have independently typed (or followed an external link) to the "old" (`page=something`) URL, but any internal links must be updated to point to the desired canonical URL, ie. `/wp-admin/something`.

Add the following immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive:

```
# Redirect direct requests for "/wp-admin/admin.php?page=something" to "/wp-admin/something"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(wp-admin)/admin\.php$ /$1/%1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `$1` backreference contains the captured "wp-admin" from the URL-path (simply saves repetition) and the `%1` backreference contains the "something" from the query string, captured in the preceding `RewriteCond` directive.

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4+) is required to remove the query string from the redirect response.

The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is necessary to prevent the rewritten request (see below) from being redirected. Only direct requests from the client are redirected.

> and the content from `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=something` is served

Immediately after the above redirect, we need to internally rewrite the request from the requested `/wp-admin/something` back to the format the server understands, ie. `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=something`.

Add the following *after* the above redirect.

```
# Rewrite "/wp-admin/something" back to "/wp-admin/admin.php?page=something"
RewriteRule ^(wp-admin)/([^.]+)$ $1/admin.php?page=$2 [L]
```

The capturing regex `([^.]+)` excludes the dot so that it naturally avoids matching requests of the form `admin.php`, thus preventing a rewrite loop. The alternative is to avoid rewriting requests that map to physical files, but filesystem checks are relatively expensive so are best avoided if possible.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write a  comprehensive reply. I really appreciate it! It worked like a charm.

Comment: Really well explained ++